# How do I find the local IP address on a Win 10 UWP project

Tags: c#, ip, uwp

I am currently trying to port an administrative console application over to a Win 10 UWP app. I am having trouble with using the System.Net.Dns from the following console code.

How can I get the devices IP

Here is the console app code that I am trying to port over.

```
public static string GetIP4Address()
{
    string IP4Address = String.Empty;
    foreach (IPAddress IPA in Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()))
    {
        if (IPA.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        {
            IP4Address = IPA.ToString();
            break;
        }
    }
    return IP4Address;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may try like this :

```
private string GetLocalIp()
{
    var icp = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();

    if (icp?.NetworkAdapter == null) return null;
    var hostname =
        NetworkInformation.GetHostNames()
            .SingleOrDefault(
                hn =>
                    hn.IPInformation?.NetworkAdapter != null && hn.IPInformation.NetworkAdapter.NetworkAdapterId
                    == icp.NetworkAdapter.NetworkAdapterId);

    // the ip address
    return hostname?.CanonicalName;
}
```

the answer above is also right

Comment: I'm having a difficult time deciding which one of these to use so I will go back to the answer check mark after a little bit of experimentation.

Comment: It appears that they both work but I marked the second one because it was in a method that returned a string just like my original example. It's also a little bit more like "my style" of coding preference. Thanks folks, you guys saved the day.

Comment: This code returns, indeed and for sure, the local IP address, the 'other code' returns the IP Address that your device or local network uses to go out on internet.

Comment: This throws LINQ exception - sequence contains more than one matching elements in my case (as I wrote in other comment I also have a Virtual Switch set up by VirtualBox in my list of adapters). I changed it to FirstOrDefault instead of SingleOrDefault to bypass this and it returned the Ipv6 address. See my answer for a fix to get Ipv4 one

Comment: also that other answer by @panda can return wrong answer (in my case the address of the virtual switch set up by VirtualBox)

Answer (score 14):

Use this to get host IPaddress in a UWP app, I've tested it:

```
    foreach (HostName localHostName in NetworkInformation.GetHostNames())
    {
        if (localHostName.IPInformation != null)
        {
            if (localHostName.Type == HostNameType.Ipv4)
            {
                textblock.Text = localHostName.ToString();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

And see the API Doc [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.connectivity.aspx)

Comment: this won't work if you have say VirtualBox, in my case the expression NetworkInformation.GetHostNames().FirstOrDefault(name => name.Type == HostNameType.Ipv4)?.DisplayName ?? "???"; was returning the IP addess of the Virtual switch setup by VirtualBox

Comment: To explain why this works, [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.hostname.ipinformation?view=winrt-19041) say *The IPInformation property is only set when the HostName object is a local IPv4 or IPv6 address returned by the GetHostNames method. This property represents the IPInformation object for the local IP address. If the HostName object is not a local IPv4 or IPv6 address, this property will be null.*

Comment: Can I ask, since I have multiple DCHP address (for Wi-Fi and Ethernet), how can I ensure I always get the Wi-Fi address? Since the loop breaks on the first instance, is this because the Wi-Fi address will always be first?

Answer (score 5):

based on answer by @John Zhang, but with fix to not throw LINQ error about multiple matches and return Ipv4 address:

```
   public static string GetFirstLocalIp(HostNameType hostNameType = HostNameType.Ipv4)
    {
        var icp = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();

        if (icp?.NetworkAdapter == null) return null;
        var hostname =
            NetworkInformation.GetHostNames()
                .FirstOrDefault(
                    hn =>
                        hn.Type == hostNameType &&
                        hn.IPInformation?.NetworkAdapter != null && 
                        hn.IPInformation.NetworkAdapter.NetworkAdapterId == icp.NetworkAdapter.NetworkAdapterId);

        // the ip address
        return hostname?.CanonicalName;
    }
```

obviously you can pass HostNameType.Ipv6 instead of the Ipv4 which is the default (implicit) parameter value to get the Ipv6 address

Comment: note that after I added the HostNameType check in the LINQ query it stopped throwing exception about multiple matches, but to be safe I changed SingleOrDefault to FirstOrDefault

Comment: wonder why somebody downvoted this answer that is the one that corrects the others (which where returning wrong IP addresses)

Comment: This is the best answer. Not sure why this was down-voted either as your answer is the best code to use for most scenarios.  Also, FirstOrDefault is the best LINQ method to use here as well since there can be multiple IP addresses IPV4 or IPV6 on a machine.  Call the function GetFirstLocalIP() and all is well.

Comment: indeed, renamed