# Can UWP apps communicate via network?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, server, uwp

Can UWP apps communicate via network?

I tried running the [Sockets Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets) from MSDN. The communication works, but only within the same app. If I try to connect to the socket from another app, the socket does not seem to receive any data.

I set the capabilities properly (Internet (Client & Server), Internet (Client) and Private Networks (Client & Server)).

I tried copying the same client code to another UWP app, but it fails to communicate to the server app (however, it hangs, the connection is not refused if the server app is running). I tried communicating with the socket from a .NET Console application. This also failed.

I viewed the related post ([Connecting two local uwp Apps on same machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38897774/connecting-two-local-uwp-apps-on-same-machine)) and made sure not to run the server on `localhost`, but rather to run it on a local address as suggested in [How do I find the local IP address on a Win 10 UWP project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33770429/how-do-i-find-the-local-ip-address-on-a-win-10-uwp-project).

However, this did not help. The socket is only reachable from within the server UWP app.

When I run `netstat -a`, I can see the app listening on 0.0.0.0:1337. I also tried on 127.0.0.1, localhost and my LAN IP. I tried disabling Windows Firewall, but it did not help.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The Server must start before Client connects.  So on one PC you start only the Server and then on the Client PC you use only the connect method.  The server always listens on localhost and client always connect to IP address of PC (either local or remote).  Some PCs you need to use localhost and other use loopback 127.0.0.1.  There is a host file on a PC and some are setup different.

Comment: I know all of this. It does not work.

Comment: Have you considered using [WebSockets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/websockets) instead?

Comment: There should be no reason you cannot connect to the app from another app unless the app already has made a connection.  The app should only listen and not connect.  Once it made a connection using the source ip, destination ip, and port these three items cannot be used again.  So check with cmd.exe >Netstat -a and see if the connection is complete.  If netstat indicates it is only listening then you should be able to connect.

Comment: I checked with `nestats -a` and it says it is listening. However, I still cannot connect from the other app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently, the answer is no. Packets are prevented from reaching the socket if the UWP server is on the same machine as the client.

[Socket Communication on UWP(Universial Windows Platporm)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40926902/socket-communication-on-uwpuniversial-windows-platporm)